# Deriving $\frac{\cos(n+1)\varphi\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$?

Tags: trigonometry

> I am trying to understand this derivation provided in another answer:$$s'_n(\theta)
> = {\bf Re}(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta}) \\
> = \dfrac{-1+\cos\theta+\cos n\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)} \\
> = \dfrac{-2\sin^2\theta/2+2\sin(n+\theta/2)\sin\theta/2}{4\sin^2\theta/2} \\
> = \frac{\cos(n+1)\varphi\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$$

**Note**:$\frac{\theta}{2}=\varphi$

I am stuck on the following point:

I used $\cos\theta=\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})=1-2\sin^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}$

After repacing I got:$\dfrac{-1+\cos\theta+\cos n\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)}=\dfrac{-2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-2\sin^2(\frac{n\theta}{2})+2\sin^2(\frac{(n+1)\theta}{2})}{4\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})} $

However, after some search I did not find any identity that replaced would yield me the expression $$\frac{\cos(n+1)\varphi\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}.$$

**Question:**

How can I go from $\dfrac{-2\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-2\sin^2(\frac{n\theta}{2})+2\sin^2(\frac{(n+1)\theta}{2})}{4\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}$ to $\dfrac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the second yields the third one?

Comment: `this derivation provided in another answer` Please include the respective link. You likely miscopied what was written there.

Answer (score 4):

Without considering real or imaginary versions it can be seen that:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i k \theta} &= \frac{e^{i \theta} (1 - e^{i n \theta})}{1 - e^{i \theta}} = \frac{e^{i \theta} (1 - e^{- i \theta}) (1 - e^{i n \theta})}{(1 - e^{i \theta})(1 - e^{- i \theta})} \\
&= \frac{(e^{i \theta} - 1)(1 - e^{i n \theta})}{2(1- \cos\theta)} \\
&= - \frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta/2} (e^{i \theta/2} - e^{- i \theta/2})(e^{i n\theta/2} - e^{- i n\theta/2})}{4 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)} \\
&= - \frac{(2 i)^2 \sin(\theta/2) \sin(n \theta/2)}{4 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)} \, e^{i (n+1)\theta/2} \\
&= \frac{\sin(n \theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)} \, e^{i (n+1)\theta/2}.
\end{align}
Now take the real and imaginary components to obtain
\begin{align}
Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i k \theta}\right) &= \frac{\sin(n \theta/2) \cos((n+1)\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)} \\
Im\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i k \theta} \right) &= \frac{\sin(n \theta/2) \sin((n+1)\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)} 
\end{align}

For the case of taking the Re component first:
\begin{align}
Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i k \theta} \right) &= Re\left( \frac{(e^{i \theta} - 1)(1 - e^{i n \theta})}{2(1- \cos\theta)} \right) \\
&= \frac{\cos\theta - \cos(n+1)\theta + \cos n\theta -1}{2(1-\cos\theta)} \\
&= \frac{\cos(n \theta) - \cos((n+1)\theta) - 2 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)}{4 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(n\theta + \theta/2) - \sin(\theta/2)}{2 \sin(\theta/2)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(n\theta/2) \cos((n+1)\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)},
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\cos\theta - \cos\phi &= - 2 \sin\left(\frac{\theta + \phi}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\right) \\
\sin\theta - \sin\phi &= 2 \sin\left(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\theta + \phi}{2}\right)
\end{align}
was used.